# List the values ​of cell L1 from all sheets from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a p.xlsm file that only has a "Seznam" sheet and after that I have a Book1.xlsm file where there are a lot of sheets.

I would need code in the p.xlsm file that would open the Book1.xlsm file and write the value from cell L1 from each sheets to the p.xlsm file.

I tried to come up with this code myself, unfortunately the values ​​are not output.

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Call MakeSummary
End Sub


Sub MakeSummary()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
         
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\petr.shromazdil\Desktop\Book1.xlsm")
         
    Application.Goto Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Sheets("Seznam").Cells(3, 3)

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Seznam" Then
            Workbooks("p.xlsm").Sheets("Seznam").Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ws.Range("L1").Value
        End If
    Next ws
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True        
End Sub
```

Comment: Please debug your code by going through the code step by step using F8 to see what actually happens and check the variable values while it does, to see what's going wrong. Also `Workbooks("p.xlsm").Sheets("Seznam").Range("C65536")…`  should be `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Seznam").Range("C" & Rows.Count)…` to make it work reliable. Excel has more than 65536 rows.

Answer (score 0):

### A *Workbook AfterSave*: Retrieving Data

**`ThisWorkbook` Module**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    If Not Success Then Exit Sub ' was not saved
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' You have just saved the workbook successfully while 'MakeSummary'
    ' is writing to it again leaving it unsaved.
    MakeSummary
    ' So you need to save it again. For an 'undetected' save
    ' i.e. to avoid an endless loop of saving (crashing Excel),
    ' you need to disable events,...
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ' ... save the workbook again,...
    Me.Save

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        ' ... and re-enable events.
        If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

**Standard Module (e.g. `Module1`)**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MakeSummary()
    
    Const SRC_SUBFOLDER As String = "Desktop"
    Const SRC_FILE_NAME As String = "Book1.xlsm"
    Const SRC_CELL As String = "L1"
    Const WORKSHEET_NAME As String = "Seznam"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "C"
    
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    
    Dim sFilePath As String: sFilePath _
         = Environ("USERPROFILE") & pSep & SRC_SUBFOLDER & pSep & SRC_FILE_NAME

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(WORKSHEET_NAME)
    Dim dCell As Range
    Set dCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, DST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    Dim sws As Worksheet

    For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
        If StrComp(sws.Name, WORKSHEET_NAME, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            dCell.Value = sws.Range(SRC_CELL).Value
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next sws
        
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, unfortunately it won't write anything from "Book 1" to "p"

Comment: Is there a message box? What does it say? If not, there is no data in `L1` of the worksheets, or the event never got triggered. If events are disabled, you can create a new sub and use the one-liner `Application.EnableEvents = True` to enable them. Have you tried to run `MakeSummery` manually?

Comment: "p" is workbook, where is the code (there is only sheet "Seznam"), I need open workbook "Book1" and from all sheets write L1 to workbook "p"

Comment: That is what the codes do. Did you put the codes in the correct places? The first needs to be in the `ThisWorkbook` module of workbook `P.xlsm` while the second one needs to be in a standard module of workbook `P.xlsm` e.g. `Module1` (use `Insert>Module`). Try to run `MakeSummery` manually from the VBE.

Comment: What was the cause of the problem? I'm asking so I could easier help someone else if in similar trouble.